# DNN and Quickbooks Integration

Tags: shopping-cart, dotnetnuke, quickbooks

Has anyone got any success with integrating any of the existing DNN Store or Shopping cart module with Quickbooks.

I know there is something called Quickbook SDk but didn't know much about it, like whether it can be used in a web application or not.

Share some case study or your experience if anyone achieved success using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Smith Cart will do the trick.

http://www.smith-consulting.com/products/dotnetnukemodules/shoppingcartmodule.aspx

I evaluated their demo and was pretty impressed; however, for our project I ended up rolling our own solution.

With that said, based upon their manual (link to manual at the top of that page, as of 7/18/2011), it integrates nicely with Quickbooks.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I saw this link yesterday. BTW How you tested it ? Did you download some trial version of Quickbooks as well to test.

Comment: Kunal, I did not test the QB integration, but i did test Smith Cart. I believe they allow you to demo the software for 30 days, but I believe you have to contact them first

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing web-based integration I recommend leveraging the Intuit Partner Platform, it's built for this.  More info here: http://ipp.intuit.com

Your customers can sync their data (if they are Desktop QuickBooks users) with the IPP Cloud and you access/update it per your application's needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RevIndex for DNN, you can use QuickBooks Connex for DNN:

[QuickBooks Connex for RevIndex](http://www.jmawebtechstore.com/revindex-quickbooks-connex)

It integrates with the online and desktop editions of QuickBooks.

Answer (score 0):

eCC Cloud is available in the App Center and integrates shopping carts with QuickBooks Online.  It doesn't look like they support DNN yet but you could check if they are implementing it anytime soon.

[eCC Cloud on Intuit App Center](http://appcenter.intuit.com/webgility)